# How to check if input fields are empty from two pages in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<script>
   $(function () {
      if ($('#FormFields tbody').find('input[value==""]').length === 0) {
         $("#test").html("Additional information is required.");
         }
        });
    </script>
    <label id="test"></label>
```

I have written this code to check if input fields in my 2 forms are empty or not. Somehow, its not working and the label shows no matter what.
I have one Registration page and one additional information page. If there are fields in the 'additional info page' which were not captured at the time of registration, those fields will be visible in this page. 
I wrote this jQuery code to check if there are any fields empty among those which we want from the user.
Please let me know if this code is not written well.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle with a working example so we can help you. :)

Comment: you have two equals in ('input[value==""]'), there should only be one

Comment: Why are you not using validation attributes and unobtrusive client side validation so MVC handles all this out of the box? And what do you mean _"from two pages"_?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, By 2 pages I mean, one is the 'Registration Page ' which the user sees as soon as he visits the website. The second page, is the one that user encounters once he completes the registration and where I want additional information of the user.

Comment: @DinoMyte, I tried using just on equals sign and it's still not working.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed, I am sorry but there is more to this, so unfortunately I cannot create a jsfiddle.

Comment: So which page is that script in? Its not clear what your _two pages_ have do do with anything.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This script is in the 'ADDITIONAL INFORMATION' page. For example, I have selected 10 fields that I want from the user as input. I ask the user on the 'REGISTRATION PAGE' only 6 of those fields. Next, the remaining 4 fields, I want the user to input in the 'ADDITIONAL INFORMATION PAGE'.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, But those 2 pages know that there are in total 10 fields . So, my problem is to first see if there are any input fields empty out of the total fields and if there is an input field, I want to display a label.

Comment: I suspect you want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqt01ujk/1/), but why your not using validation attributes and client side validation is beyond me.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh MY GOD! Your solution worked for me!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Could you please explain what does this line of code means:  `$.each(inputs, function(index, item)`

Comment: Its just a loop. It iterates each input in the document (as defined by `var inputs = $('input');`). Refer the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Okay! Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have one doubt to ask from the code that you suggested yesterday. My page has 2 different cards and the label shows just for one card, when I need to show the label for both the cards on that page. Is that the jQuery where I need to make the change? If you want I can post the code as well.

Comment: @dsingh23, The question is on the verge of being closed because its unclear what your asking. I suggest you delete this and ask a new question with a bit more detail and explanation including the relevant code (I don't even know what you mean by _My page has 2 different cards_). I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, This is the link to my question. Can you please help me on this one, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838049/how-can-i-loop-through-all-the-cards-in-this-code/33838375#33838375

Comment: Where on earth did you get the idea that you write code for MVC like that?